# Which relations are between 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables; `user`, `message`, and `friend`. I have to create an EER diagram, but I'm not sure which relations are between `user` table and `friend` table, and between `user` and `message` table. In `friend` and `message` tables, there are 2 columns as foreign key; `request_from_id`, and `request_to_id`. In my opinion, between the tables are relations 1:2, but I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. It's up to you to define the relations, if not given otherwiese

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong,

User Table represents any Person 
Friend Table represent Friend request sent by one person to another person
Message Table represent Message sent by one person to another person
request_from_id and request_to_id in both Friend table and Message table are foreign key to id in User Table.

User --> Friend = [1:Many] for both keys request_from_id and request_to_id
User --> Message = [1:Many] for both keys request_from_id and request_to_id

Comment: So that's One-to-Many Relationships,or many-to-many ?

Comment: I change my relations between tables, Can you write if this correct ?

Comment: Updated the answer with 1:M relationships